# tc qdisc with GRE in openwrt

Tags: openwrt, qos, trafficshaping

I'm trying to implement traffic control to GRE interface in an openwrt board. For this i followed below steps,

```
Create GRE interface named gre1 in both tunnel end devices.
Tested reachability with ping, Success.

create qdisc using following command.

tc qdisc add dev gre1 root handle 1: default 2

Before creating tc classes i tired to ping the tunnel interface but this failed. 
I tried to capture packet in gre1 but found 0 packets.

Monitored the statistics of qdisc using the command

tc -p -s -d qdisc show dev gre1

found that packet drop count is increasing.
```

I have tested this same in Ubuntu PC and found working. Also if i change the tunnel to VPN tunnel instead of GRE it working fine.

Is there any additional thing which I need to handle to implement tc in GRE ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed !

Add class

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 60kbps ceil 100kbps

then add sfq for the class

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 20: sfq
```